# Sencha Touch event delegate for multiple items

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, dom-events

I'm trying to delegate an event for multiple items by a common class name, but, it seems not to be working. Delegating for multiple IDs should work but I'm getting an error message about: "Invalid ComponentQuery selector".

This is what I have at the moment:

```
Ext.define("App.view.Main", {
    extend : "Ext.Container",

    config : {
        listeners : {
            disclose : {
                fn : "onElementDisclose",
                delegate : [ "#onelist", "#anotherlist" ] // this don't work
                // delegate : ".lists" <- this also don't work
                // delegate : "#onelist, #anotherlist" <- this don't work either
                // delegate : "#onelist" <- but this work!
            }
        },
    },

    initialize : function() {
        this.callParent(arguments);

        this.add([ {
            xtype : "slideshow",
        }, {
            xtype : "onelist",
        }, {
            xtype : "anotherlist",
        } ]);
    },

    onElementDisclose : function () {
        console.log("click");
    },

});
```

Both lists have "onItemDisclosure : true" and "cls: lists".

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

This certainly works to a degree and you don't have to delegate it in the controller as demonstrated here:

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',

    launch: function() {
        Ext.create('Ext.Panel', {
            fullscreen: true,
            title: 'Test',
            layout: 'vbox',
            items: [{
                xtype: 'panel',
                layout: 'fit',
                flex: 1,
                items: [{
                    docked: 'top',
                    xtype: 'titlebar',
                    title: 'List 1'
                }, {
                    xtype: 'list',
                    name: 'list 1',
                    cls: 'myList',
                    id: 'list1',
                    onItemDisclosure: true,
                    itemTpl: "List1 item {name}",
                    model: Ext.define('User', {
                        extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

                        config: {
                            fields: [{
                                name: 'name',
                                type: 'string'
                            }]
                        }
                    }),
                    data: [{
                        name: 'John'
                    }, {
                        name: 'Jane'
                    }]
                }]
            }, {

                xtype: 'panel',
                layout: 'fit',
                flex: 1,
                items: [{
                    docked: 'top',
                    xtype: 'titlebar',
                    title: 'List 2'
                }, {
                    xtype: 'list',
                    name: 'list 2',
                    cls: 'myList',
                    id: 'list2',
                    onItemDisclosure: true,
                    itemTpl: "List2 item {make}",
                    model: Ext.define('Car', {
                        extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

                        config: {
                            fields: [{
                                name: 'make',
                                type: 'string'
                            }]
                        }
                    }),
                    data: [{
                        make: 'Volkswagen'
                    }, {
                        make: 'Audi'
                    }]
                }]
            }],

            listeners: {
                disclose: {
                    fn: function(list, record, target, index, e, eOpts) {
                        console.log(list);
                        var greeting = '';
                        if (typeof(record.data.make) != 'undefined') {
                            greeting = "I am a car and my make is " + record.data.make + "!";
                        } else if (typeof(record.data.name) != 'undefined') {
                            greeting = "I am a user and my name is " + record.data.name + "!";
                        };
                        console.log('disclosing from list ' + list.config.name, greeting);

                    },
                    // delegate : 'list' // this works as you are querying by xtype of list
                    // delegate : 'component [onItemDisclosure]' // this works as you are targeting by attribute of onItemDisclosure
                    // delegate : '[onItemDisclosure]' // this works as you are targeting by attribute
                    // delegate : '[name="list 1"]' // this works as you are targeting by attribute of name = 'list 1'
                    // delegate : '[cls="myList"]' // this unfortunately doesn't work
                    // delegate : "#list1, #list2" <- this don't work either
                    // delegate : "#list1" <- but this work!
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
```

However there are some pitfalls with the above as you can see.

Demo: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/g49

Answer (score 0):

You cannot fire same function using common events on multiple control defining listeners in view.

Yes you can do the same in controller. it will work undoubtedly..

Thanks
Sachin